# How to access database on Heroku from Android through RESTful APIs?

Tags: java, database, rest, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to learn how to make calls to RESTful Web Services from Android.
I wanted to test my app against some free database available online and that's when I came to know about Heroku.

I want to develop a Java web app on Heroku that will implement my RESTful web services and fetch data from Heroku database based on the requests received. But I have no clue where to begin.

Where should I begin and how should I connect a Web app deployed on Heroku to a database on Heroku itself? Where do I begin designing the DB itself?

I'm sorry if this question is repetitive.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read these article:

[Creating Backend APIs for Android Apps with Heroku and Retrofit](http://jkutner.github.io/2016/08/18/android-backend-api-heroku-retrofit.html)

[Using Database-backed RESTful Services on Heroku with Android](http://jkutner.github.io/2016/08/19/android-database-rest-service.html)

You should also follow one of these guides to get familiar with Heroku itself:

[Getting Started on Heroku with Java (Maven)](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#introduction)

[Getting Started with Gradle on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-gradle-on-heroku#introduction)

Comment: Thanks! My app is now successfully deployed on Heroku